# Who designed and built Rans S-7 airplane?

Tags: aircraft-design

I read in the [Washington Times](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2014/aug/31/ohio-man-builds-own-bush-plane-then-learns-to-fly/), that a man named Swingle, who has no knowledge and experience in aircraft design, built one which he called a bush airplane. But I read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rans_S-7_Courier), that the RANS S-7 series seems different as it was built by a company, Rans Inc, seems after the founder name, Randy Schlitter.

Does anyone know the complete story about the aircraft, the engine specification, the size, the weight, the dimension, etc, of that Rans S-7 as mentioned in the Washington Post article? It is interesting as it can land in a savanna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ran's S-7](https://www.rans.com/s-7s-courier) is a kit plane. The article didn't clearly state it, but the gentleman from Ohio bought a Rans kit and assembled it himself, he didn't design the aircraft, he put a kit together.

Comment: Oh I see. I though that he build himself, as mentioned in the article he need 21 months to finish his airplane.

Comment: He did build it, but he didn't design it. You can buy kit planes and assemble them yourself.

Comment: What is that mean built but didn't design? Is like he used someone's design?

Comment: He bought a kit, complete with blueprints (plans). Not unlike buying a model car that you glue together. All the pieces and instructions were provided to him, he just followed them and put the parts together.

Comment: So, it is clearly that he didn't build it? If he just follow a design, can not be said that he built it his own.

Comment: He *did* build it though. He just didn't engineer it. Just because you use parts/plans doesn't mean you don't build it.

Comment: Where did the design he get? Is it from Rans Inc?

Comment: Yes, that is part of the kit that he buys. He gets all the needed parts and the plans, he takes those plans and puts it together to assemble an airplane. Rans sells the parts and the plans, he builds it.

Comment: @AirCraft Lover: Perhaps the distinction between "design" and "build" would be a question better suited for the English language site.

Comment: @AirCraftLover many companies sell DIY packages containing everything you need to build an aircraft except the tools (rivet guns, screwdrivers, etc.). Just follow the instructions and put it together, like a plastic model kit (but obviously a lot more parts and accuracy needed).

Comment: @jwenting, thank you for the info. What else company that sell such as kits?

Comment: How much it probably will cost if I buy it a complete kits **include** the engine?

Comment: @AirCraftLover Vans are a large supplier. Total cost depends heavily on your selected options (specific aircraft type, engine, avionics, etc.).

Comment: @AirCraft Lover: Use Google (or other search engine, if you prefer).  About $25K for the basic kit.

Comment: @jamesqf, yes my friend, I will. I just curious actually, and curios if any from all of you have bought one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the webpage for purchasing a Rans S-7S Courier airplane.

https://www.rans.com/s-7s-courier

You can buy a kit that needs assembly, or you can by an already assembled airplane (Ready to Fly).

Final cost depends on the options you select for the kit, or for the factory assembled airplane.

Comment: Thank you my friend. Very interesting.